# Testing soft asserts not marking test as failed

Tags: testng, assertions

I am using soft asserts to report verification failures. However the soft asserts do not seem to work and do not report the method as failed. Can anyone help me out with what might be the issue.

I am using testing version 6.8.

```js
SoftAssert sassert = new SoftAssert();
String str1 = "String 1";
String str2 = "String 2";

sassert.assertEquals(str1,str2,"Failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `sassert.assertAll();` after all softAssert calls.